# java game picture not display

Tags: java, graphics, embedded-resource, getresource

I make 2D game in AWT and I had all files in one package. Now I divided files into some packages. Images, which I called with:

```
ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(image));
img=ii.getImage();
```

now I call with:

```
ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon("cz/ryska/awtgame/images/"+image);
img=ii.getImage();
```

This code is in class in package `cz.ryska.awtgame.basic`

But when I start game, displays game scene but not display images. Scene is empty. But any Java error is not induced. Images are probably found but not display. What is problem?

Comment: If these images are delivered with your app., use `getResource`.

Comment: Besides loading images, is there any code in your project that actually is supposed to *paint* images?

Comment: Ok, I will try getResource().  maksimov: Yes in my code are procedures for painting. Painting was functional before I change package structure.

Comment: Ok thanks!! I use URL and all is allright!

Answer (score 1):

> ..Painting was functional before I change package structure.

You did more than change the package structure. The change is that the first is loading an image by `URL`, while the 2nd is loading an image from a `File` (where the `String` represents the path). An `URL` can be used with an embedded resource, while a `File` cannot.

See the [info. page on `embedded-resource`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for further info.